# Decision Tree split error

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

During the split function of the decision tree, I am getting an assertion error stating:

```
Error > Assert: type(C) == dict
```

I couldn't find any errors in the code up until now. Could you please correct it if there is any problem with it?

My code:

```
def split(X,Y,i):

    def __find_best_split(self):
                best_split = {}
                for column in self.X:     
                information_gain,split = 
    self.__find_best_split_for_column(column)
                    if split: continue
                    if not best_split or best_split["information_gain"] 
       <information_gain:
                       best_split = 
    {"split":split,"col":column,"information_gain":information_gain}

                    C= (best_split)     

                return C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __find_best_split(X, Y, i):
best_split = {}
for column in X:     
    information_gain,split = (2,3)#self.__find_best_split_for_column(column)
    if not split: continue
    if not best_split or best_split["information_gain"] <information_gain:
        best_split = {"split":split,"col":column,"information_gain":information_gain}
C= (best_split)
return C
```

I ran this code in python 3.7 and it gave me the correct output: `{'split': 3, 'col': 'a', 'information_gain': 2}`. Also as pointed out by [Ben Reiniger](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/58852/77981), it should be `if not split: continue` rather than `if split: continue`. In your case based on the indentation, C should never get defined or if indented properly, it should give empty dictionary. In both the scenario, getting error `assert type(C) == dict` does not makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context (and a more cleanly formatted code block) would probably be helpful, but shouldn't the line
`if split: continue`
be instead the opposite,
`if not split: continue`?

It seems to me that the `continue` to go to the next column in the `for` loop should only be happening if `__find_best_split_for_column` fails (in case at a particular node the column is constant).  As written, the `continue` will take effect nearly every time, making `best_split` and therefore `C` never get redefined.  Then again, this *should* just mean `best_split` remains an empty dictionary, so failing the type check seems odd.  (That definition of `C` is supposed to be happening outside the loop, right?)

Comment: Hi @Ben, i tried changing the code as per your suggestion, but it still gives the same error.